# Laravel validation for arrays

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-validation

I have this request:

```
GET http://example.com/test?q[]=1&q[]=2&q[]=3
```

And I have this route:

```
Route::get('test', function(Request $req) {
    $req->validate(['q' => 'array']);
});
```

How should I do to add other validation rules to each element of this array using Laravel validator? For example, I want to check that each `q` value has a minimum of 2.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried based on the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: Oh I didn't see this part, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation about [validating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays).

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

You can also do this in your controller using the Request object, [documentation about validation logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic).

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
  ]);

  // The blog post is valid...
}
```

There is a third option for when you have a lot of validation rules and want to separate the logic in your application. Take a look at [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests)

1) Create a Form Request Class

```
php artisan make:request StoreBlogPost
```

2) Add Rules to the Class, created at the app/Http/Requestsdirectory.

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
  ];
}
```

3) Retrieve the request in your controller, it's already validated.

```
public function store(StoreBlogPost $request)
{
  // The incoming request is valid...

  // Retrieve the validated input data...
  $validated = $request->validated();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Route::get('test', function(Request $req) {
    $req->validate([
        'q' => 'array',
        'q.*' => 'min:2'
    ]);
});
```

For more information on validation of arrays, see => [laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays](http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I got an array of users

```
users: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jack",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jon"
    }
]
```

I would validate it like below :

```
$request->validate([
    'users[*]'=> [
        "id" => ["integer", "required"],
        "name" => ["string", "required"]
    ]
]);
```

Here * acts as a placeholder