# Laravel validator for input arrays

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

First and foremost:

- I did read both entries @ [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832109/laravel-validation-for-arrays)

I am trying to validate an array containing input[text]. They are defined currently as:

```
<input type='text' name='user[0][name]'/><div>@error('user[0][name]'){{ $message }}@enderror</div>
<input type='text' name='user[1][name]'/><div>@error('user[1][name]'){{ $message }}@enderror</div>
```

I tried the 3 variants below as well:

```
<input type='text' name='user[][name]'/>
<input type='text' name='name[]'/>
<input type='text' name='name[0]'/>
```

My **ExampleController** does this, in the **store()** method:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'user.*.name' => 'required|string',
    ])->validate();
```

I've also tried using:

```
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        "user.*.name"    => "required|string",
    ]);//*/
```

The other option that I've tried to use to match was (for the other case):

```
    'name.*' => 'required|string',
```

None of these manage to print an error message in the **div** that follows the input.

The only way for me to get to see the error, is if I do the validation in of the two below (for each case):

```
"user[0][name]"    => "required|string",
"name[0]"          => "required|string",
```

So... what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user[0][name]` is the correct syntax for naming your form input elements.

To access the error message(s), however, use dot notation: `user.0.name`.

Here's a working [playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/46b7b12b-9271-4f78-b2b8-d5f722d8f94a).

Comment: That was it. Thanks!